# Find the shock curve and a weak solution for a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I have the following problem that asks to find the shock curve for the following IVP
$$u_t + (u^2)_x = 0, \quad u(x,0) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x},$$
to then obtain a weak solution from this curve using Rankine Hugoniot condition. I'm pretty lost on how to raise the problem. In Evans there is an example where it is easy to get u^- and u^+, so we can solve for the shock curve using an ODE. In this case, does anyone have an idea how to raise the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to get shock curve analytically, but i computed your PDE numerically
with the additional boundary condition: $u(0,t)=\frac{1}{2}$

[image: Shock curve]

From the simulation it's to be seen that the shock curve is $x=t$.
I know that my answer is mathematically not satisfying, sorry.
Perhaps it helps you anyway.

Comment: Hi ! Of course it is of interrest to compare the numerical computation to the analytic solution. But the conditions (initial or boundary) must be the same. Unfortunately this is not the case with your condition $u(0,t)=\frac12$ which is very different from $u(x,0)=\frac12 e^{-x}$. In the case of $u(0,t)=\frac12$  there is a trivial solution $u(x,t)=$constant$=\frac12$ which satisfies both the PDE and the condition. This is far to be the case with the condition $u(x,0)=\frac12 e^{-x}$. It should be very interresting if the result of numerical calculus from your software would be shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

$$u_t+2u\,u_x=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{2u}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from necessarily $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{2c_1}$
$$x-2c_1t=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u=F(x-2u\,t)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).
$$u(x,0)=\frac12 e^{-x}=F(x)$$
So the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $(x-2u\,t)$ :
$$u=\frac12 e^{-(x-2u\,t)}$$
This is the solution ( on implicit form) of the PDE which satisfies the condition.

In order to obtain the explicit form of the solution we have to solve for $u$ the implicit equation. This is not possible with the elementary functions. A special function is necessary, the LambertW function : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html . The result is :
$$\boxed{u(x,t)=-\frac{1}{2t}W\big(-e^{-x}t\big)}$$
For $\quad t\to 0\quad$ then $\quad W\big(- e^{-x}t\big)\to - e^{-x}t\quad$ which shows that the condition is satisfied.

Considering the properties of the Lambert $W(X)$ for negative argument $\quad X=-e^{-x}t\quad$ real solution exists in the range $-e^{-1}<X<0$. Moreover the function is multivalued. So they are two real solutions separated by $-e^{-1}=X=-e^{-x}t$
$$t=e^{x-1}$$
The problem is fully solved on the pure mathematical viewpoint. Since the Rankine Hugoniot condition is a more physical notion the context of the problem should be known in order to discuss the validity of the above solution.